# Defining worker's data range in Spark-Python

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

Spark:
I have a sequential data of length **'n'** (a1, a2,...ak,...an). I have to perform **fun**(a1, a2,...a5), **fun**(a5,a6,...a9),......**fun**(an-4...an-2,an-1,an), Where **fun** is a mathematical operation and is applied on data blocks independently.
I want these blocks should execute in parallel. Do I have luxury of supplying beginning and end range for executors (for each block)? [Block size is variable but uniform].

Comment: please be more specific and share data, code and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an index:

```
rdd_indexed = rdd.zipWithIndex()
```

Generate buckets:

```
with_buckets = rdd.mapValues(lambda x: x % 5)
```

Swap:

```
swapped = rdd.map(lambda xi: (x[1], x[0]))
```

And `reduceByKey`:

```
swapped.reduceByKey(f)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution with quick response. 
Can I have bucket with overlapping values e.g. overlapping-strip size of 'm' where 'm'< 'k' means last 'm' values of a bucket is same as first 'm' values in next bucket?

Comment: secondly function: fun is to be applied on all values of a window at a time the above mentioned way is treating one index at a time which is not solving the purpose.